# What is the best approach to detecting the number grid in a Gnome 2048 game image?

Tags: python-tesseract

[GNOME 2048 game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKy2X.png)Want to generate number grid from image above.
e.g.
`[4, 4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [2, 4, 0, 2], [2, 2, 0, 0]`

simple pytesseract fail to detect numbers.
So converted to grayscale still the detection fails.
Even converting image to black and white fails detecting numbers. [if all blocks contain number the detection works but fails if any of the block is blank.]

The only approach remains is to cut image into 16 pieces and check using matchTemplate. Can anyone suggest smart approach to detect number grid from image above?

code below works for full numbers but not if any of the block is blank.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


_, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
result = np.zeros_like(image)
result[mask == 255] = [255, 255, 255]  # Set white color (BGR value)
cv2.imwrite('temp.png', result)

cv2.imshow('White Color Only', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'  # Optional: Custom configuration parameters
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, config=custom_config)
print(text)
```